# From array to array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to transform an array like the following:

```js
const myArray = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ];
```

to something like this:

```js
const transformedArray = [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd' ], [ 'e', 'f' ] ];
```

The only way I see is to do it with a good old for loop, but is there a more elegant way to do it with `Array.prototype` functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other solution that has been given to me which I find the most readable.

```js
const myArray = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ];
const transformedArray = Array(myArray.length / 2).fill().map((_, i) => [myArray[i * 2], myArray[i * 2 + 1]]);
console.log(transformedArray);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) and `%`

```js
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

const newArray = myArray.reduce((acc, a, i) => {
  const index = Math.floor(i/2);
  acc[index] = acc[index] || [];
  acc[index][i % 2] = a
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(newArray)
```

- `Math.floor(i/2)` gets which of the inner array the item belongs to
- `i % 2` gets which postion of the inner array the item belongs to

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create an array of chunks:

```js
const myArray = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' ];

const chunk = n => arr => 
  Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / n) }, (_, i) =>
    myArray.slice(i * n, (i + 1) * n)
  );
  
const log = arr => console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

log(chunk(2)(myArray)); // [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"],["g"]]
log(chunk(3)(myArray)); // [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution below uses `reduce` to iterate over the items in the array. We use a modulo check on the index of the item to determine whether or not we need to start a new array.

The code adds in an object when it's inspecting an index which doesn't need to be formed into a new array. We later `filter` these objects out. There may be a more elegant way of doing this, but I feel it works out quite nicely.

```js
const letters = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' ];

const splitIntoChunks = (arrayIn, size) => arrayIn.reduce(
  (prev, curr, i) => [
    ...prev,
    i % size === 0
       ? arrayIn.slice(i, i + size)
       : { '__remove': true }
  ],
  [],
).filter(x => !x['__remove'])

const result = splitIntoChunks(letters, 2)

console.dir(result)
```